# Filtering a datetime column

Tags: python, datetime, filtering

I have a dataframe with two columns: DateTime and x.

```
DateTime = [‘2005-10-02’,’2005-10-03’,’2005-10-04, ‘2005-10-15’,’2005-10-16’,’2006-11-04’, ’2006-11-05’, ’2006-11-06’, ’2010-01-21’, ’2010-01-22’, ’2010-01-23’, ’2010-01-25’]

x = [20,29,31,22,25,25,21,29,28,22,21,26]
```

I want to create a new dataframe with only those dates and x when the x >= 25 for the first time, and then select the next date such that the difference between the two dates is minimum 150 days. So the result would look like:

```
DateTime = [‘2005-10-03’,’2006-11-04’,’2010-01-21’]
x = [29,25,28]
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is an example of a function that performs the column based filtering:

```python
def filter_cols(x, DateTime):
    from datetime import datetime

    # dt1, dt2 are tuples of the form (int, <datetime.datetime object>) 
    # checks if the difference, in days, 
    # between two datetime objects is at least equal to 'days'
    cond = lambda dt1, dt2, days=150: abs((dt1[1] - dt2[1]).days) >= days

    def filt(it, li=[]):
        try:
            if not li:
                li.append(next((xi, di) for xi, di in it if xi >= 25))
            li.append(next(df for df in it if cond(li[-1], df) and df[0] >= 25))
            filt(it, li)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
        finally:
            return li

    # preprocessing step
    # parse DateTime elements into datetime objects
    dt = list(map(lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d'), DateTime))

    # main step        
    # call filtering function
    li_tup = filt(zip(x, dt))

    # if li_tup is empty return two empty lists
    if not li_tup:
        return [], []

    # postprocessing step
    # split the list of tuples into two tuples
    x_filt, dt_filt = zip(*li_tup)

    # format dates back to their string representation
    dt_filt = list(map(lambda dt: dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), dt_filt))    
    
    return list(x_filt), dt_filt
```

Bear in mind that the function can be written more densely, but the steps are broken down for clarity.

While it is not clearly stated I assume that your `DateTime` list
is sorted in increasing chronological order.

Having made this assumption, the main idea behind the example above
is to first parse the `DateTime` list into an object that
can manipulate date data and provide the days difference functionality. 
This is achieved through the use of the built-in `datetime` module but you can use whatever suits you best. The `map()` function applies the `strptime()` classmethod of the `datetime` class, to `DateTime` in order to parse the string elements into the aforementioned datetime objects, and returns an iterator that is converted into a list.

The `filt(it, li: list=[])` function accepts an iterator and an argument that defaults to an empty list but can be initialized, should be needed. The list holds tuples that are valid `x` and `DateTime` element pairs e.g. `[(29, datetime.datetime(2005, 10, 3, 0, 0)), (25, datetime.datetime(2006, 11, 4, 0, 0))]`

When `li` is an empty list, the following block inside `filt()` appends the first `x`,
`Datetime` tuple to the list, so that `x` is at least equal to `25`:

```python
 if not li:
    li.append(next((xi, di) for xi, di in it if xi >= 25))
```

In order to filter the `DateTime` column the iteration is resumed until a date, x pair tuple that satisfies the conditions set in the problem statement is found. The utility function `cond(li[-1], df)` returns `True` if the difference between the datatime object in the last tuple of `li` and the datetime object in the current tuple yield by the iterator have a difference of at least `150` days. The other condition is that x (df[0], the first element of the current tuple) has to be at least equal to `25` again. This is my assumption, as it is not clearly stated in the problem statement whether or not a pair that satisfies the date difference condition is allowed if its corresponding `x` is less than `25`. Please feel free to omit the second condition`df[0] >= 25` if that is the case.

```python
next(df for df in it if cond(li[-1], df) and df[0] >= 25)
```

and

```python
cond = lambda dt1, dt2, days=150: abs((dt1[1] - dt2[1]).days) >= days
```

the difference in days between the two objects is stored in the datetime's `days` attribute.

Then the function recursively calls itself after the `next` valid tuple is appended to `li`.
The recursion ends when the `it` iterator is consumed, raising a `StopIteration` exception.

The postprocessing step, converts the list of tuples into two tuples by unwrapping `filt()`'s output and then calling `zip()`.

```python
x_filt, dt_filt = zip(*li_tup)
```

An additional step, formats the filtered list of `datetime` objects back to a string.

The `filter_cols()` function returns the two filtered columns.

Example run:

```
 >>> filter_cols(x, DateTime)
     ([29, 25, 28], ['2005-10-03', '2006-11-04', '2010-01-21'])
```

Comment: Added a couple of lines to check against  li_tup being empty, an edge case that occurs when no element in x satisfies the condition of being at least equal to 25. Should this be the case, then two empty lists are returned.

Comment: So kind of you for the detailed explanation. Grateful for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, if the answer solves your problem perhaps you could consider accepting it, as this might potentially help others with a similar problem, too.